# TT Transformation fails on loading EnvDTE._Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-2019, envdte

We are using T4 templates in our project to generate C# code. The templates inspect the current solution and projects using DTE like this:

```
DTE dte = (DTE)((IServiceProvider)Host).GetService(typeof(DTE)); 
Solution solution = dte.Solution; 
Project project = solution.Project("...");
```

Recently the engine started to fail with the error below. There was no change in the template or relevant code, so I believe this is to do with some visual studio / .NET update. But I have no idea how to fix this.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'EnvDTE._Solution, CodeGenerationUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall.ResolveMethod(Boolean bThrowIfNotResolved)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall..ctor(SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMsg, ArrayList deserializedArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE._Solution.get_Projects()
   at XXXXX.CodeNavigator.Projects(Solution solution) in C:\XXXXX\CodeNavigator.cs:line 29
   at XXXXX.CodeNavigator.Project(Solution solution, String name) in C:\XXXXX\CodeNavigator.cs:line 24
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating7C92645F4B28BF7FDF611D165F2230AA45B6BB3184F9527C2F8B592506527D4AC5FBE363A1B068750F0082F78E0BBE35E12B9F21E89803E59119D9A2834641A7.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this happens only when I use "Run Custom Tool" (or Save the TT file). When I run the template with "Debug T4 Template" it generates the output without any issues.

Comment: Since latest update (VS 16.3.2) all T4 code is now interpreted as xml. Maybe this is a problem on the MS side now.